# Qt combobox items under item

Tags: c++, qt

Can I achieve something like in the picture using qt designer combobox?

Combobox items under item

[image]

Comment: i think that will be possible, how about adding something you have tried and someone can help you out.

Comment: This widget can not be obtained with Qt Designer, you must create a custom widget that has that behavior.

Comment: What about using a `QMenu` and style it properly?